# Polymer 2.0 $$() does not work

Tags: polymer-2.x

In Polymer 1.x where `this.$$('some selector')` was working, what is the equivalent in Polymer 2.0 since `this.$$()` doesnt work anymore?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$$` is deprecated in `Polymer 2.x` instead you'll have to use something like

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector
```

If you really want to use `$$` you can use it from [LegacyMixin](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/mixins/Polymer.LegacyElementMixin) which has all the deprecated methods. As `LegacyMixin` internally extends `Polymer.Element` you only need to extend LegacyMixin.

```
class MyElement extends  Polymer.LegacyElement
```

Comment: For completeness sake, could you show how to add the mixin? Thanks.